# OpenMP error in Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am trying to execute the inner double loop in parallel (in serial there is no problem):

```
DO J=1,NY
    DO I=1,NX

        A2=0.0d0

        A1=S(I,J)
        A2=dble(S(IP(I),J)+S(IM(I),J)+S(I,JP(J))+S(I,JM(J)))

        EL=0.0d0

        !$OMP parallel DO SHARED(LAMDA,S,COUL) PRIVATE(I1,J1) reduction(+:EL) 

        DO J1=1,NY
            DO I1=1,NX

                IF ((J1/=J.OR.I1/=I).AND.(J1/=J.OR.I1/=IP(I)).AND.(J1/=J.OR.I1/=IM(I)).AND.(J1/=JP(J).OR.I1/=I).AND.(J1/=JM(J).OR.I1/=I)) THEN 

                    IF (ABS(FLOAT(I)-FLOAT(I1)) <= ABS(FLOAT(I)+LEN-FLOAT(I1))) THEN 
                        ID= INT(ABS(FLOAT(I)-FLOAT(I1)))
                    ELSE 
                        ID= INT(ABS(FLOAT(I)+LEN-FLOAT(I1)))
                    END IF

                    IF (ABS(FLOAT(J)-FLOAT(J1)) <= ABS(FLOAT(J)+LEN-FLOAT(J1))) THEN 
                        JD= INT(ABS(FLOAT(J)-FLOAT(J1)))
                    ELSE 
                        JD= INT(ABS(FLOAT(J)+LEN-FLOAT(J1)))
                    END IF

                    EL=EL + LAMDA*COUL(ID,JD)*dble(S(I1,J1))

                END IF

            END DO
        END DO

        !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

....

where COUL(ID,JD) is a matrix that has been computed earlier in the code, LAMDA a parameter and the matrices S, IP etc. have all known values.

When I compile it (Intel Fortran) I get the following weird errors:

```
error #7655: A variable is required in this OpenMP* context.   [3.0D0]
error #7656: Subobjects are not allowed in this OpenMP* clause; a named variable must be specified.
```

Anyone has any idea about these errors?  The funny thing is that I wrote a simple program just doing these loops, and it works fine in parallel with the above OpenMP statements.

Comment: Are you sure it comes from this section of code? I don't see any 3.0D0

Comment: When I use Intel Fortran and it raises errors and warnings it always provides the numbers of the lines it doesn't like.  Could you indicate which lines in the snippet you have posted are the ones that the compiler balks at ?

Comment: The error is the line of the OpenMP directive. I didn't see 3.0d0 either :). 3.0d0 is the value for the PARAMETER LAMDA. When I changed the OpenMP directive to: !$OMP parallel DO SHARED(S,COUL) PRIVATE(I1,J1) reduction(+:EL) the error message vanished. But unfortunately the program chrases...

Comment: Parameters are named constants, not variables. Also you have to make `ID` and `JD` private.

Comment: LAMDA IS A REAL(8) PARAMETER, IT'S DECLARATIONS IS: **REAL(8), PARAMETER:: LAMDA**. When I modify the OpenMP directive to:**!$OMP parallel DO SHARED(S,COUL) PRIVATE(I1,J1) reduction(+:EL)** the compiler shows no error (no need to make **ID,JD** private, it works the same way), but at run time the program crashes when it enters the parallel loop

Comment: As Hristo sais, `parameter` is not a variable. You have to use a variable in that context.  And you do need to make `ID` and `JD` private, they are in a race condition now.

Comment: @VladimirF you mean there is a problem when I use a previously defined parameter inside a loop? LAMDA is defined in the statement part of the program and can be used anywhere in it, no?

Comment: There are no problems in using parameters inside loops. It's only that parameters are always shared and are not allowed in any `PRIVATE`, `SHARED`, etc. OpenMP clause. And yes, you have to make `ID` and `JD` private.

Comment: @HristoIliev Hristo you are right about the parameters, that's what I figured out by trial too. I made **ID,JD** private Now I don't get a compilation error but the program aborts at run time just when it enters the parallel loop.

Comment: @HristoIliev I run it in linux with ifort:    ifort -O3 -warn all -xSSE4.2 -parallel -par-report[1] -openmp -o run.out Source1.f90 and I got the run-time error message: 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' I suppose this has something to do with stack size(?) I used the command 'ulimit -s unlimited' prior to compiling. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3474189 Not sure if this will be the solution. I think that in addition to Yes, you have to use 'ulimit -s unlimited' you have to tell to your compiler to use a memorry model that allow you to create all the private coppies involved in the parallel computing. For instance, if you use 10 threads you will create 10 copies of somme array leading to insufficient memory. You can manage this via the flag -mcmodel=medium or -mcmodel=large. By the way nothing is mentionned about the variable LEN, is it shared private or ...?